# Error: Invalid type code in stream 'Invalid'

Tags: c#, serialization, ipc, pipe, named

Presently, I am attempting to serialize a queue of objects, send them over named pipes, and then deserialize and re-construct the queue on the receiving application.  At this time I am using BinaryFormatter, but when the Deserialize is called on the receiving side (i.e., at line binFormat.Deserialize(memoryStream)), I get this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'MySysTrayApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MySysTrayApp.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 

Error: Invalid type code in stream 'Invalid'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadValue(InternalPrimitiveTypeE code)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadMemberPrimitiveUnTyped()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at EnvisionSystemTray.Form1.DeserializeNamedPipeData(Byte[] buffer) in c:\MyApp\Form1.cs:line 937
   at EnvisionSystemTray.Form1.WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult ar) in c:\MyApp\Form1.cs:line 889
```

So far, I have found this webpage that relates to a Microsoft bug fix,

http://www.ikriv.com/blog/?p=1358

But when I attempt to install the update I am getting this message:

```
KB982638 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
```

At this time, I am using .NET Framework 4.5.1.  Here is some of the stripped down code that I am using:

```
    // Pipe Server application:
    public Form1()
    {
        // ...

        // Create the new async pipe 
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            Constants.SYS_TRAY_PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.In, 1, 
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        // Wait for a connection
        pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
            new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);

        // ...
    }

    private void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int rxBufferSize = Constants.MAX_MESSAGE_QUEUE_COUNT;
            // Get the pipe
            NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)ar.AsyncState;
            // End waiting for the connection
            pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(ar);

            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[rxBufferSize];

                // Read the incoming message
                pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, rxBufferSize);

                BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

                // Convert byte buffer to list of data items
                MyQueueObject[] dataObjects =
                    binFormat.Deserialize(memoryStream);

                // ...
               memoryStream.Close();

                // ...
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_ackInterval);
            }
        }



    // Pipe Client application:
    private void ConstructExternalClientNamedPipes()
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".",
            Constants.SYS_TRAY_PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.Out,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        _lstExternalNamedPipeClients.Add(pipeClientStream);
    }

   private void ExternalClientNamedPipeCommunication()
    {
        // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to 
        // become available
        foreach (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClientStream in
            _lstExternalNamedPipeClients)
        {
            if (!pipeClientStream.IsConnected)
            {
                pipeClientStream.Connect();
            }
        }

        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _lstExternalNamedPipeClients.Count; i++)
            {
                NamedPipeClientStream pipeClientStream = 
                    _lstExternalNamedPipeClients[i];

                if (pipeClientStream.IsConnected)
                {
                    ExternalClientWriteSerialization(pipeClientStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    _lstExternalNamedPipeClients[i] = null;
                }
            }
            // Remove all clients that are no longer connected
            _lstExternalNamedPipeClients.RemoveAll(
                    x => x == null);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_ackInterval);
        }
    }

    private void ExternalClientWriteSerialization(
        NamedPipeClientStream pipeClientStream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream memoryStream =
            new MemoryStream(MyQueue.Count);
        binFormat.Serialize(memoryStream,
            MyQueue.ToArray);
        pipeClientStream.BeginWrite(
            Utility.ObjectToByteArray(memoryStream),
            0,
            Convert.ToInt32(memoryStream.Length),
            AsyncTransmitCallback,
            pipeClientStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

FYI, this is where I got the ObjectToByteArray function:

[How to convert an object to a byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I just fixed the problem.  Instead of using this function:

```
ObjectToByteArray(memoryStream)
```

I simply call the following, since a MemoryStream object is essentially a byte array deep down:

```
memoryStream.ToArray()
```

Thank you for anyways for your considerations.