# USQL using ARRAY_AGG on user defined type

Tags: u-sql

## UDT

```
[SqlUserDefinedType(typeof(StudentHistoryFormatter))]
    public struct StudentHistory
    {
        public StudentHistory(int i, double? score, string status):this()
        {
            InstitutionId = i;
            Score = score;
            Status = status;
        }

        int InstitutionId { get; set; }

        double? Score {get; set; }

        string Status { get; set; }

        public string Value()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", InstitutionId, Score, Status);
        }
    }
```

For simplicity I did not even put the class in a namespace.
I registered the assembly with the USQL database

## USQL

```
@history =
    EXTRACT InstitutionId int,
            Score double,
            Status string
    FROM @"CoreData\Institution\history.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

@historyMap =
   SELECT InstitutionId,
               ARRAY_AGG<StudentHistory>(new StudentHistory(InstitutionId, Score, Status)) AS History
        FROM @history
        GROUP BY InstitutionId;
```

## Error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       E_CSC_USER_INVALIDCOLUMNTYPE: 'Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql.SqlArray' cannot be used as column type. 
>   Description:
>   The column type must be a supported scalar, complex or user defined type.
>   Resolution:
>   Ensure the column type is a supported type. For a user defined type, make sure the type is registered, the type name is fully qualified, and the required assembly is referenced by the script.

Comment: not sure why I got a down vote for this question!

Comment: Drive-by downvotes are an occupational hazard on SO.  I have upvoted it to balance it out : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit unclear. Currently, the only supported item types in a SqlArray are the built-in scalar and complex (SqlArray, SqlMap) types. User-defined types are currently not supported.

You can model it either by creating your own ArrayofUDT user-defined type or serialize the UDT into the byte[].

Here is an example of the latter with ARRAY_AGG, assuming you have a ToBinary() method that allows you to convert the UDT to byte[]:

```
@data = SELECT key, ARRAY_AGG( myUDT.ToBinary() ) AS obj_array FROM @input GROUP BY key;
```

(see [How to convert an object to a byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp) for information about object serialization options)

Then when you want to get the object back, you would use CROSS APPLY EXPLODE on the object array and use the byte[] to rehydrate the UDT instance. Pseudo-code:

```
@objects = 
  SELECT myUDT.FromBinary(data) 
  FROM @data CROSS APPLY EXPLODE (obj_array) AS t(data);
```

Please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback for UDT in complex types. I will file a bug against the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. however I am still a bit unclear about the part of using ArrayOfUDT with ARRAY_AGG.. is there a resource you can point me to that will clarify how to use this ?

Comment: Creating your own array UDT would not work work ARRAY_AGG. So what you should do then is to serialize your UDT to byte[] before using ARRAY_AGG. I added an example into the answer.