# How to serialize very large files to a byte array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, .net-5

I have a custom object. One of the properties on the object is a byte array with the contents of a file. This file can be VERY large (800+ MB in some instances). Since using the `JsonSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` are out of the question (the resulting string is too large), I think going with a byte array is the next best option.

I've looked through some other solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp)) but currently have no luck with what I need. We're working out of .NET 5 and things like the `BinaryFormatter` are no-go.

Is it somehow possible to take my object and write it to a stream so I can deal with it in a byte array?

Thanks

Comment: You can use one of the existing formats for serialization. [`MessagePack`](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) for example or [`protobuf`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net)

Comment: Also consider changing that property from a byte array to a Stream, so you don't have to hold it all in memory

Comment: It would be nice to know what is the purpose of such serialization? Are you sending those files over network? Uploads a file to a DB? You may try `Response.OutputStream.Write` to [write file chunks to the response stream](https://forums.asp.net/t/2172345.aspx?Fastest+way+to+read+a+very+large+pdf+file+as+byte+array+and+view+in+in+ASP+NET+Web+Forms+4+application) (if file is being downloaded)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I'd be willing to try a stream. I've been trying to figure out how to get it working with a ```StreamContent``` object or ```MemoryStream``` as well.

Comment: @oleksa I'd be sending the file across to our API for the purpose of putting in our database. We're taking video files and ultimately saving them as a byte array.